# Counting values in a dictionary that are greater than a certain number in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm looking to create a function that prints a count of the number of times a grade is found to be greater than or equal to 90.

So if the dictionary is:

```
d = {'Luke':'93', 'Hannah':'83', 'Jack':'94'}
```

The output should be 2

I get the following error when trying to run my code:
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Tom'

```
def overNum():
    d = {'Tom':'93', 'Hannah':'83', 'Jack':'94'}
    count = 0


    for number in d:
        if int(number) in d and int(number) >= 90 in d:
            count += 1

            print(count)
```

if the user inputs: numTimes()   the output should be:

```
2
```

Comment: Dicts iterate keys by default.  `int(number) in d` is equivalent to `int(number) in d.keys()`, so the error come from casting `int("Tom")`.  To iterate values you need `d.values()` or both key-value pairs, use `d.items()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for number in d:` will iterate through the keys of the dictionary, not values. You can use

```
for number in d.values():
```

or

```
for name, number in d.items():
```

if you also need the names.

Answer (score 3):

You can collect the items in a list that are greater or equal to 90 then take the [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len):

```
>>> d = {'Luke':'93', 'Hannah':'83', 'Jack':'94'}
>>> len([v for v in d.values() if int(v) >= 90])
2
```

Or using [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to sum booleans without building a new list, as suggested by [@Primusa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553892/counting-values-in-a-dictionary-that-are-greater-than-a-certain-number-in-python/56553927#comment99689037_56553927) in the comments:

```
>>> d = {'Luke':'93', 'Hannah':'83', 'Jack':'94'}
>>> sum(int(i) >= 90 for i in d.values())
2
```

Comment: Might I suggest `sum(int(i) >= 90 for i in d.values())` to count instead of building a list

Comment: `v >= "90"` should suffice to save conversions to int.

Comment: @pylang What would `"100" > "90"` return?

Comment: @Selcuk I stand corrected.  I had in mind something like `"93" > "90"`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter`:

```
len(list(filter(lambda x: int(x[1]) > 90, d.items())))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the key-value pairs in the dict with `items()`

```
def overNum():
    d = {'Tom':'93', 'Hannah':'83', 'Jack':'94'}
    count = 0

    for name, number in d.items():
        if int(number) >= 90:
            count += 1
    print(count)
```

Also there are some issues with the `if` statement that i fixed.

Comment: or just `d.values()`